# jQuery append if doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to append a `div` only if it's not already there. I am trying with this but it doesn't work:

```
$('#method_id').on('change', function (e) {

    if ($(this).find("option:selected").data('method-column-id') != 1) {
        if ($('#column_message').next('div').length)
            $('#column_message')
                    .append('<div id="warning_message" class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Warning!</strong> Installed column and method do not match</div>');
    } else {
        $('.form-group').find('#column_message>.alert').remove();
    }
});
```

And if I remove the second if-clause, it gets appended every time I select an option which passes first if-clause

Here is the HTML

```
<!-- Warning message -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="group" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div id="column_message" class="col-md-6">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems your code needs to be changed in various places. But, it's not completely clear what are you doing. Please make a fiddle with HTML codes as well.

Comment: Careful now! Your use of `next` suggest the `div` in question is a sibling of `#column_message` while use of `append` suggests the `div` is a child of `#column_message`!! **`.append( content [, content ] )` ... Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In order to check if an element exists, you need to find a selector that matches only that element and check if the length of the jQuery object is equal to 0 or not, like so:

```
if ($('#unique-selector').length === 0) {
    // code to run if it isn't there
}
else {
    // code to run if it is there
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are appending div with id, you could just search if that div exists
by calling :

```
if($("#warning_message").length > 0 ){
   $('.form-group').find('#column_message>.alert').remove();
}else{
   $('#column_message').append('<div id="warning_message" class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Warning!</strong> Installed column and method do not match</div>');
}
```

But if you would like to have more divs of alert, you could just search for class "alert" or so.

Another way without id ( probably better ) would be to use 
[children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method

Answer (score 2):

the inner if should be `if ($('#column_message').next('div').length===0)` or `if(!$('#column_message').next('div').length)`